# Download the Grafana Agent Operator Custom Resource Definitions (CRDs)

Tags: grafana-mimir

I am unable to download this link which is available in grafana-mimir official documentation
link- https://github.com/grafana/agent/tree/main/production/operator/crds.

looking for somebody support to download that link
as it showing below in document
Download the Grafana Agent Operator Custom Resource Definitions (CRDs) from https://github.com/grafana/agent/tree/main/production/operator/crds.